# Mediawiki process tag after templates tranclusion

Tags: tags, mediawiki

Is there any way to do something like that.
I have next wiki text:

```
{{template_open_tag}}
{{template_some_data}}
{{template_close_tag}}
```

And there are templates:

{{template_open_tag}}

```
<my-tag>
```

---

{{template_some_data}}

```
bla-bla-bla...
```

---

{{template_close_tag}}

```
</my-tag>
```

---

But tag '<bold>' processed already when first template transluded and wiki render this page like:

```
bla-bla-bla...
</my-tag>
```

But I want to see:

```
**bla-bla-bla...**
```

In my extension:

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'myTagInit';

function myTagInit( &$parser ) {
   $parser->setHook( 'my-tag', 'myTagRender' );
}

function myTagRender( $input, $args, $parser, $frame) {
   return "**".$input."**";
}
```

Thank you.

P.S.
And don't ask me why I need this strange markup and don't want to use something like this:

```
{{template_tag|{{template_some_data}}}}
```

And {{template_open_tag}} like:

```
<my-tag>{{{1}}}</my-tag>
```

Comment: let me see if i got you right: Do you want to get the text in {{template_some_data}} bold?

Comment: for me this renders as <bold> bla-bla-bla... </bold>

Comment: as in the html doesn't work, it just puts the code in the document.

Answer (score 2):

To warn you -- this sort of structure will likely be phased out entirely in future versions of MediaWiki, due to its inconsistent behavior and the difficulties it causes with structures like tags and sections.

The correct and future-proof way to do it is indeed to contain both your start and end in one template and pass the middle in as a parameter, eg {{template_tag|{{template_some_data}}}}

Comment: I temporararily did so while searching for an answer. I see that this is a better way. Maybe you're right and I'll stay on this version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set [$wgUseTidy](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgUseTidy) to `true` to make MediaWiki remove unclosed tags only after all the templates have been evaluated. Alternatively, you can use wikimarkup - as Adrian said - which does not suffer from this limitation.

**Update:** AFAIK XML-style extension tags are evaluated before way template including happens, so piecing them together from multiple templates is not possible. (Event `<ext>{{{1}}}</ext>` does not work pre-1.16, though you can make it work in 1.16 with `recursiveTagParse`.)

Comment: '$wgUseTidy = true;' works only for HTML tags. But I need to make mediawiki (not browser) process only closed tags. To understand this let's rename '<bold>' to '<my-extension-tag>'.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<bold>` use `'''` in both your {{template_open_tag}} and {{template_close_tag}} and it should render as **bla-bla-bla...**

Also, you can't do:

```
{{template_open_tag}}
{{template_some_data}}
{{template_close_tag}}
```

You have to do

```
{{template_open_tag}}{{template_some_data}}{{template_close_tag}}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work if you put {{template_open_tag}}{{template_some_data}}{{template_close_tag}} with no line break?

Comment: No. It still doesn't work. And I don't want to put it all in one line 'cos it's not readable if I put more then one template between like this: {{template_open_tag}}{{template_some_data1|param1|param2|param3}}{{template_some_data2|param1|param2|param3}}{{template_some_data1|param1|param2|param3}}{{template_some_data3|param1}}{{template_close_tag}}